# Why my class is not found on Heroku while it does on local environment?

Tags: php, heroku

I have a tiny project that is working correctly in my local environment. But when I push it to Heroku, an exception is thrown saying:

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'App/Controllers/Home/HomeController' not found in /app/App/Controllers/Controller.php:158
```

Here's the method where the exception is thrown:

```php
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public static function executeFromRoute()
{
    // This method checks the URI and finds the correct class to use.
    // Because I am trying to access the root URL, it should returns:
    // "App/Controllers/Home/HomeController"
    $controllerClass = self::getControllerClass();
    $controllerAction = self::getControllerAction();

    $controller = new $controllerClass; // LINE 158

    if (!method_exists($controller, $controllerAction)) {
        throw new \Exception('Action not found.', 500);
    }

    return $controller->$controllerAction();
}
```

The file `HomeController` has been correctly uploaded to the git repository of Heroku:

```
> heroku run "ls App/Controllers/Home"
Running ls App/Controllers/Home on ⬢ MY_SUB_DOMAIN... up, run.6604 (Free)
HomeController.php
```

I already executed `heroku run "composer install"` and `heroku run "composer dump-autoload"`.

I didn't alter the content of the `Procfile` file:

```
web: heroku-php-apache2
```

I specified my `App` directory within my `composer.json` file:

```
{
    (...),
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "App"
        }
    }
}
```

I don't get **why my class is not found on Heroku while it does on local environment?**

Did I miss something?

Comment: 'I already executed `heroku run "composer install"` and `heroku run "composer dump-autoload"`'—don't do this. All files that your site needs must be included or generated *at build time*. Any changes that you make to the filesystem afterwards will be lost.

Comment: @Chris - Yeah, I found out these commands were executed at build time a bit later... Thanks for your comment, actually I managed to know why I got this exception, and there was no relation with how Heroku is working. I will answer myself.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was present on Heroku and not on my local environment because Heroku is on **Linux** while I am on **Windows**. I read many posts about warnings on **how important letter cases and separators (`/` and `\`) are on Linux**, but I didn't find a solution with my first tries.

But I finally found out.

My `Controller::getControllerClass()` method returned `App/Controllers/Home/HomeController`, but it should return `\App\Controllers\Home\HomeController` instead in order to create an instance of it.

So I replaced:

```php
$controller = new $controllerClass;
```

By:

```php
$controllerClass = '\\' . str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '\\', $controllerClass);

$controller = new $controllerClass();
```